# What kind of htaccess rules would I need to accommodate files within folders?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm rewriting my portfolio website urls by using the following code in a htaccess file,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#remove enter code here.php; use THE_REQUEST to prevent infinite loops
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ (.*)\.php\ HTTP
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ $1 [R=301]

# remove index
RewriteRule (.*)/index$ $1/ [R=301]

# remove slash if not directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
RewriteRule (.*)/ $1 [R=301]

# add .php to access file, but don't redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]
```

It all works until I want to navigate to another page from the blog-post.php page
for example, let say I want to go to the about page the url becomes cgarcia.design/web/about and it should be cgarcia.design/about so the page can load properly. **Now what would I need to change in the htaccess file to accommodate files within folders?**

my nav structure is the following

- work
- about
- resume
- blog - posts folder - entry
- contact

Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the ned of your document:

```
RewriteRule ^$ web/ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/$1
```